# Auto increment is lower than total rows

Tags: php, mysql, innodb

I created a php script that takes values from 1 table and inserts them into another.

This executes pretty quickly (`1000` rows per second).

Everything went well. There are no duplicates in the table and I think all the values from the other table are inserted.

But something strange caught my attention:

There are a total of `903388` rows in the table but the highest ID that has auto-increment enabled is `898582`.
That's a difference of `4806`.

The other table has almost the same amount of items as the ID but that is always off by a bit due to the original table always getting new values.

Due to such a large database a MRE could not be produced

So now my question is:

How can the auto-increment value be lower than the total amount of rows?

The datatype of the original tables ID:

```
bigint(20)
```

The datatype of the IMAGES table ID:

```
int(11)
```

Show create table IMAGES;

```
CREATE TABLE `IMAGES` (
  `ID` int(11) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `SRC` varchar(300) CHARACTER SET utf8mb4 COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_520_ci DEFAULT NULL COMMENT 'Pad naar afbeelding',
  `VERWIJDERD` tinyint(1) NOT NULL DEFAULT 0 COMMENT '0=image is online, 1=image is verwijderd',
  `DATUM` datetime NOT NULL DEFAULT current_timestamp() COMMENT 'Datum van upload',
  `IP` varchar(15) CHARACTER SET utf8mb4 COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_520_ci DEFAULT NULL COMMENT 'ip van uploader',
  `SITE` tinyint(1) DEFAULT NULL COMMENT 'site waar image is geupload',
  `OID` int(11) DEFAULT NULL COMMENT 'occasion id',
  `POSITIE` int(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT 0 COMMENT 'sorteer id',
  `TYPE` tinyint(1) NOT NULL DEFAULT 0 COMMENT '0=normaal 1=schade',
  PRIMARY KEY (`ID`),
  KEY `OID` (`OID`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=898583 DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1
```

My PHP script that fills the table:

```
<form action="" method="post">
  <label for="fname">Rijen:</label><br/>
  offset<input type="number" name="offset"><br/>
  amount<input type="number" name="amount"><br/>
  <button type="submit" name="submit">Go</button>

</form><br/>
<?php
    $per_insert = 100;

    if(isset($_POST['submit'])){
        echo "Offset: ".$_POST['offset']."<br/>";
        echo "Limit: ".$_POST['amount']."<br/>";
        $msc = microtime(true);
        $count = (is_numeric($_POST['offset']) ? (int)$_POST['offset'] : 0);
        $amount = (is_numeric($_POST['amount']) ? (int)$_POST['amount'] : 0);
        $qcount = 0;
        $filter_array =  array('images/occ/', null, '');
        for ($i = $count+$per_insert; $i <= $amount; $i+=$per_insert){
            $valuesq = array();
            $olddataq = $mysqli->query("SELECT `ID`,SITE,DATUM,IP,`IMG_1`,`IMG_2`,`IMG_3`,`IMG_4`,`IMG_5`,`IMG_6`,`IMG_7`,`IMG_8`,`IMG_9`,`IMG_10`,`IMG_11`,`IMG_12`,`IMG_13`,`IMG_14`,`IMG_15`,`IMG_16`,`IMG_17`,`IMG_18`,`IMG_19`,`IMG_20`,`IMGS_1`,`IMGS_2`,`IMGS_3`,`IMGS_4`,`IMGS_5`,`IMGS_6`,`IMGS_7`,`IMGS_8`,`IMGS_9`,`IMGS_10`,`IMGS_11`,`IMGS_12`,`IMGS_13`,`IMGS_14`,`IMGS_15`,`IMGS_16`,`IMGS_17`,`IMGS_18`,`IMGS_19`,`IMGS_20` FROM `OCCASIONS` LIMIT ".$per_insert." OFFSET ".$count.";");
            $qcount++;
            $schade = $normaal = 0;
            while($olddata = $olddataq->fetch_assoc()){
                $olddata = array_diff($olddata, $filter_array);
                $id = $olddata['ID'];
                $datum = $olddata['DATUM'];
                $ip = $olddata['IP'];
                $site = $olddata['SITE'];
                unset($olddata['DATUM']);
                unset($olddata['ID']);
                unset($olddata['IP']);
                unset($olddata['SITE']);
                while ($data = current($olddata)) {
                    $key = explode('_',key($olddata));
                    if($key[0] == 'IMG'){
                        //normale image
                        $datacheck = check_fotodata($data, $id, $key[1], 0);
                        if($datacheck === false){
                            $valuesq[] = "('".$data."','".$datum."','".$ip."',".$site.",".$id.", ".$key[1].", 0,0)";
                        }else{
                            $valuesq[] = $datacheck;
                        }
                    }else{
                        //schade image
                        $datacheck = check_fotodata($data, $id, $key[1], 1);
                        if($datacheck === false){
                            $valuesq[] = "('".$data."','".$datum."','".$ip."',".$site.",".$id.", ".$key[1].", 1,0)";
                        }else{
                            $valuesq[] = $datacheck;
                        }
                    }
                    next($olddata);
                }
            }
            $count += $per_insert;
            //var_dump($valuesq);
            $mysqli->query("INSERT INTO IMAGES (SRC, DATUM, IP, SITE, OID, POSITIE, TYPE, VERWIJDERD) VALUES ". implode(",", $valuesq));
            $qcount++;    
        }
        $msc = microtime(true)-$msc;
        echo "buildtime: <br/>";
        echo $msc . ' s<br/>'; // in seconds
        echo ($msc * 1000) . ' ms<br/>'; // in millseconds
        echo $qcount . "<br/>";
        $msc = microtime(true);
    }
    
    function check_fotodata($image, $oid, $pos, $type){
        global $qcount, $mysqli;
        $checkdataq = $mysqli->query("SELECT * FROM FOTODATA WHERE KID = ". $oid ." AND IMG = '". $image ."'");
        $qcount++;
        if($checkdataq->num_rows > 0){
            $checkdata = $checkdataq->fetch_assoc();
            if($checkdata['INFO'] == 'Verwijderd'){
                $del = 1;
            }else{
                $del = 0;
            }
            return "('".$checkdata['IMG']."', '".$checkdata['DATUM']."', '".$checkdata['IP']."', '".$checkdata['SITE']."', '".$checkdata['KID']."',".$pos.",".$type.",".$del.")";
        }else{
            return false;
        }
    }
```

Comment: Edit your question to show (as text, not an image) output of `show create table yourtablename;`

Comment: Show your php insert code?

Comment: ... also check what is minimal ID value in source table.

Comment: auto increment columns must be part of an index: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/innodb-auto-increment-handling.html

Comment: @AlanBirtles both ID and OID are indexed

Comment: please show a [mre]

Comment: @AlanBirtles that is not possible due to the size of both tables

Comment: Why do you think there are 903388 rows in the table?

Comment: We don't need the full data but the full schema and a stand-alone script to populate the tables is certainly possible

Comment: Also , LIMIT without ORDER BY is fairly meaningless

Comment: @Strawberry I know but the database was created in 2016 by someone with not much sql knowledge and now a big system that runs 3 sites 24/7 runs on it so normalizing wil take a long time that's why i'm turning all the images in the occasions table to an image table

Comment: And see about sql injection and the importance of prepared and bound queries

Comment: @Strawberry this is purely a script to transfer images after that the script is deleted and there are 903388 rows because phpmyadmin returns 903388 total records

Comment: @AlanBirtles I added both tables in a dbfiddle

Comment: The figure is an estimate

Comment: What have you tried to resolve the problem? How did you determine the number of rows?

Comment: The `903388` total records from phpmyadmin is just an estimate. Execute `select count(*) from table_name` for exact total records.

Comment: @Strawberry you are right I dod not know that. I executed count(*) and got the maximum id value returned thnx for explaining me pls add a answer

Comment: @AlanBirtles - I'm not sure, but I think `id` must be _first_ in some index.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Please check count of table by below query first then compare. Count of table and max id should be equal if you use auto_increment_offset  1 and auto_increment_increment 1 in MySQL.

> select count(*) from IMAGES;

Please comment what you find.

Comment: Please share more details. What do you mean by "count from php code"? What do you mean by "duplicate rows"?

Comment: There cannot be duplicates. This answer is wrong and misleading

Comment: If rows have been deleted or ids burned, `MAX(id)` will be larger than `COUNT(*)`.

Comment: It is not possible for `MAX(id)` to be less than `COUNT(*)`, nor are duplicates possible -- But there is another requirement to make those true:  `id` must be declared `PRIMARY KEY` or `UNIQUE` _by itself_.

Comment: "Duplicate", in this context, probably means "two rows with the same `id`".